# Cannot get to fastboot/bootloader menu on xiaomi mi5

Tags: factory-reset, fastboot, xiaomi, hard-reset

I have forgotten pattern/passcode for my brand new Xiaomi Mi5. So, I need to do a factory reset to recover the access.

However, when I try to boot to the fastboot/bootloader menu (using power and volume keys, as instructed on other posts), it gets stuck at the screen showing the fastboot logo and a little white animal fixing the little android robot (which appears to be the fastboot logo). No menus are displayed for reset etc. It just doesn't go past this screen.

I've also tried installing the android SDK to try and run commands from PC command line, but -

a) I cannot find the commands

b) The device is not being recognised by the PC. But I'd rather just factory reset manually if possible, cause the SDK way looks complicated.

Comment: Fastboot != recovery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, where exactly do I enter this 'command', if that's what it is?

Comment: != means that it is different than

Comment: so fastboot is not recovery

Comment: You should be able to enter recovery mode using the key combo VOL_UP+POWER. The thing is, due to security concerns, the official recovery might not allow you to wipe from it. If that's indeed the case, you WILL have to flash an official ROM via fastboot.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use your google account to recover the locked phone?
Anyway, if not, keep the device on, the type in cmd `adb devices`

If the device is not displayed you should, in effect, flash a ROM, in order to use it again, if the phone asks for permissions give them to it and do `adb reboot recovery`

Then you can proceed to wipe the data

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131934/discussion-on-answer-by-nicola-galluccio-cannot-get-to-fastboot-bootloader-menu).